# Auto populating the self registration page with the values from an API response

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

[image]I have a requirement where, if the user enters the the email id in the self registration page of wso2 identity server. i have to call my API such that if the email ID is alraedy stored in database, my API will give the response which contains first name last name and address and other details of user so that i can auto populate those fields in self registration page of wso2 identity server 5.10 which I'm using. So in which back end service (in which class & in which package ) should i call the API so that i can auto populate the values in self registration page of wso2 identity sever. The API is present in the API manager.Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I hope you plan to change the following UI to get the user's email address.
[image]

That Page URL is `https://<host>:<port>/accountrecoveryendpoint/register.do?...` which is mapped to **self-registration-username-request.jsp** file https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/blob/v1.0.72/apps/recovery-portal/src/main/webapp/self-registration-username-request.jsp
So, you can invoke your API via httpclient from this JSP file.

Next, the user will be redirected to `/accountrecoveryendpoint/signup.do` which is mapped to `self-registration.jsp`. There, you can handle the attribute population.

You can find the servlet-mapping to JSP pages easily from this web.xml file
https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/blob/v1.0.72/apps/recovery-portal/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: Hi @Anuradha, the original requirement here is when the user enters his National ID as posted in the above screenshot, I will have to call an API in the back end so that if the user's national ID is valid i will get the user details from the response of an API, which i have to populate in the user registration form. But i have to call the API through back end code. So can u please help here so as to which JAVA code should be used and let me know where to implement it.